# Adding a button of my Etsy page on my Facebook page

Tags: facebook-pages

How do I add my Etsy page as a button on my Facebook page (next to Likes, Photos)?

Answer (score 1):

As explained on this [Etsy Help](http://www.etsy.com/help/article/1439) page:

> First, make sure you're signed out of Facebook in the same browser.
>
> Then, go to **`Your Shop`** > **`Info & Appearance`** and scroll down to the **`Links`** section.
>
> (If your shop isn't open yet, go to **`Your Shop`** > **`Preview`** and click **`Get Social`** on the right.)
>
> Click **`Link a Facebook Page with your shop`**.
>
> A new window will pop up asking you to sign into Facebook.  If you manage multiple Facebook pages, you will see a list of the pages to choose from. If you manage one page, your shop will automatically choose your page.
>
> (You can't connect the same Facebook Page to multiple Etsy shops.)